# Работа с вещественными числами. Подпоследовательность

Tags: java, числа, строки

Дана последовательность вещественных чисел, разделенных запятой. Нужно найти минимальную отрицательную подпоследовательность.

Пример на целых числах . 1,2,3,4,-1,-2,2,4,5,6,2,1,-2,-4,-5 - минимальная - -1,-2.

Как это реализовать?

Есть код, его логика - перевод всех чисел >=0 в 0, числа <0 - в 1. Потом обрабатывать строку вида 0000110000111, а в ней уже смотреть на самую длинную последовательность единиц.

Как связать строку вида 0000110000111 со строкой вида 1,2,3,4,-1,-2,2,4,5,6,2,1,-2,-4,-5?

Просто вывести надо как раз таки числа из второй строки. А если попадаются 2 подпоследовательности одинаковой длины, то нужно выбрать наибольшую, то есть, надо их еще сравнивать.

Comment: Ну, запоминайте их индексы. Или заведите структуру из двух полей, для первоначального числа и 0/1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Temp
{
    private static class Pair
    {
        String sequence;
        Integer startIndex;

        public Pair(String s, Integer i)
        {
            this.sequence = s;
            this.startIndex = i;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, -2, -4, -5, 12, -1, -4};
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            b[i] = a[i] >= 0 ? 0 : 1;
            sb.append(b[i]);
        }
        //Получаем все последовательности
        List<Pair> list = getAllSequence(sb.toString());
        int min = list.get(0).sequence.length();
        //получаем список минимальных последовательностей
        List<Pair> newPair = list.stream().filter(p -> p.sequence.length() <= min).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Pair minPair = newPair.get(0);
        int minSum = getSum(minPair.startIndex, minPair.sequence.length(), a);
        //ищем последовательность с минимальной суммой
        for (int i = 1; i < newPair.size(); i++)
        {
            int w = getSum(newPair.get(i).startIndex, newPair.get(0).sequence.length(), a);
            if (w < minSum)
            {
                minPair = newPair.get(i);
            }
        }
        int[] c = new int[minPair.sequence.length()];
        System.arraycopy(a, minPair.startIndex, c, 0, minPair.sequence.length());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c)); // [-2, -4]
    }

    private static int getSum(int startIndex, int count, int[] a)
    {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            s += a[i + startIndex];
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static List<Pair> getAllSequence(String s)
    {
        List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(1+)").matcher(s);
        int lastIndex = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            String group = matcher.group(1);
            int i = s.indexOf(group, lastIndex);
            lastIndex = i;
            list.add(new Pair(group, i));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Возножно не самое простое/лучшее решение, но рабочее.

**UPDATE**
StreamApi можно переписать так

```
List<Pair> newPair = new ArrayList<>();
for(Pair p : list) {
    if(p.sequence.length() <= min) {
        newPair.add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: List<Pair> newPair = list.stream().filter(p -> p.sequence.length() <= min).collect(Collectors.toList());    Что за -> . Компилятор ругается.

Comment: StreamApi, который доступен в java8. См update ответа.